# How connect intellij idea to glue endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, apache-zeppelin, aws-glue

I have created glue developer endpoint but have no idea how attach intellij idea zeppelin notebook to it?

Here is how dev endpoint looks like:

[image]

Here is Intellij Idea screenshot:

[image]

[Plugin link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10023-intellij-zeppelin)

What user/password to use? What port should be used for connection? (I have tried to redirect `8080`, `9007` still can not connect) How to establish connection via ssh?

Comment: Probably its not supported to connect IntelliJ, though dev endpoint can be connected to professional pycharm [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-pycharm.html)

Comment: I do not believe in that :) Intellij idea is the same as PyCharm, but with different plugins. Also pyspark uses scala spark inside. Dev endpoint contains scala terminal info so definetely it should work.

Comment: @Cherry are you running Windows or unix based system? You need to establish SSH port forwarding, ie tunnel, that is defined with UNIX command in first screenshot "SSH Tunnel to remote interpreter".

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a local ssh port forwarding as described in this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-local-notebook.html

Then you should be able to use localhost:9007.